# Try and except multi-choice quiz - break not breaking out of while loop

Tags: python

If I type y to play both quizzes it still asks again and doesn't break out of the loop.

```
run = "y"

while run.lower() == "y":
    print("Starting now")

    while True:
        try:

            play = input("Do you want to play? y/n: ")
            if play.lower() == "y":
                print("Quiz A starting now.")
                #function quiz_a()
                while True:
                    try:

                        play_again = input("Do you want to play again? You will be doing Quiz B. y/n: ")
                        if play_again.lower() == "y":
                            print("Quiz B starting now.")
                            #function quiz_b()
                            print("Thanks for playing! Goodbye.")
                            break
                    except ValueError:
                        print("Please type y/n. ")
            elif play.lower() == "n":
                print("Goodbye")
                break
            else:
                break
        except ValueError:
            print("Please type y/n.")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did the value of `run` change? No? Then why should that loop exit?

Answer (score 1):

Break doesn't break out of the loop because there is another loop called while true. Remove this loop, and break will work.

Code:

```
while run.lower() == "y":
    print("Starting now")
    try:

        play = input("Do you want to play? y/n: ")
        if play.lower() == "y":
            print("Quiz A starting now.")
            #function quiz_a()
            while True:
                try:

                    play_again = input("Do you want to play again? You will be doing Quiz B. y/n: ")
                    if play_again.lower() == "y":
                        print("Quiz B starting now.")
                        #function quiz_b()
                        print("Thanks for playing! Goodbye.")
                        break
                except ValueError:
                    print("Please type y/n. ")
        elif play.lower() == "n":
            print("Goodbye")
            break
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please type y/n.")
```

Comment: ok now can u please run the code and see why it keeps looping? also it still doesn't break out I think there is something else that is wrong

Comment: @Robthemaster I don't have the full code, so I gave an estimated guess. run is not defined in your code.

Comment: @Robthemaster I ran what limited code I had and it works. 
```Do you want to play?```

``` y/n: n```

```Goodbye```

```Process finished with exit code 0```